# Add AnimatorSet to a FragmentTransaction created dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-animation, fragmenttransaction

I've created a `AnimatorSet s1`.

I want to use the `s1 AnimatorSet` instead of the `R.anim.slide_in_top` .

How do I tell the `transaction` to use `s1`?

```
private void showsystemerror(int i){
    dialog.cancel();
    Systemerror frag = new Systemerror();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("type", i);
    frag.setArguments(bundle);
    final AnimatorSet s1 = new AnimatorSet();
    final ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(frag, "x", 150,0);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    s1.play(anim);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_top, 0);
    transaction.add(R.id.main, frag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in `onCreate` to your `Systemerror` class. Be sure to replace `returnFrag` with your return `variable`.

```
    final AnimatorSet s1 = new AnimatorSet();
    final ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(returnFrag, "x", 150,0);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    s1.play(anim);
    s1.start();
```